# Case conditions in sql server ? For Decimals data type?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In Sql server, i am trying to write a query, if the value is less than zero i want to show " < 0 " other wise the same value. For this i wirte a simple query Like This :
I know it is giving conversion erro but can you help in this.

```
declare @ret decimal = 0.25    
select (case when @ret <0 then  '< 0'  else  @ret  end) as colum
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, pay attention on precision modifiers about decimal

```
declare @ret decimal(10,5) =0.25
select case when @ret < 0 THEN '< 0'  ELSE cast(@ret as varchar) end as colum
```

Comment: Yes, because it > 0, try this with -0.25, or change the type to decimal(10,2) as an option

Comment: sorry i change my query please check it, actually at the time of preparing question i wrongly typed please find my edied question

Comment: Maybe the OP meant to say that they had already changed the question by the time they were posting that comment. Either way, this seems to answer the question in its present form.

Answer (score 1):

SInce you've not specified precision and scale for `@ret` variable, scale would be `0` by default (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):  `The default scale is 0`), just specify scale while declaring variable:

```
DECLARE @ret DECIMAL(10,2) = 0.25 

SELECT 
     CASE 
          WHEN @ret < 0 THEN '< 0' 
          ELSE CAST(@ret AS VARCHAR)
    END
```

Comment: SELECT @ret would display `0` as well, this is not a question of CASE operator you've asked about

Comment: Your CASE is returning different types depending on the condition. Numbers take precedence over strings (in SQL Server), so the engine would attempt to convert `'< 0'` to a number and fail.

Answer (score 0):

basic Example when using `CASE` in `TSQL`:

```
declare @iDec decimal(10,5) = 10.5
SELECT   ProductNumber, 
      Category =
      CASE ProductLine
         WHEN @iDec > 1 THEN 'Greater Than 1'
         WHEN @iDec < 1 THEN 'Less Than 1'
         ELSE 'Equal to 1'
      END,
      Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
```